# Why can't a closed interval on R be written as the disjoint union of countably infinite many closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

As stated in the title: Why can't a closed interval $[a,b]$ on R be written as the disjoint union of countably infinite many closed intervals $[a_i,b_i]$?

Comment: Bounded both above and below?

Comment: That's what bounded means, @TimRaczkowski In any event, what is an unbounded closed interval $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I know that's what bounded means.  I was making sure that the OP understood that.